# How can one access a superclass?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm utilizing inheritance and need to access a parent's variable.
How can I achieve this?

```
class EFPaymentObject: NSObject {

    var price: NSString = "1200"
    var title: NSString!
    var desck: NSString!
    var hasPass: Bool!

    func getPrice() -> NSString() {
       return price
    }
}

class EFGoodsPayment: EFPaymentObject{

    var pay: NSString = "1"
    var type: NSString = "3"
    //var select_club_id: NSString = EFBuyBasket.sharedInstance.getClubId()
    var goods: NSString = ""
    var money = price      // doesn't work
    var money = getPrice() // doesn't work either
}
```

Comment: You can't set a default value that refers to the superclass.  You can access super class properties during the initialisation process.  Refer to the Swift programming book

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I keep your example, you can access the `price` property of the superclass during initialization of the childclass and set a default value for `money` like this:

```
class EFPaymentObject: NSObject {

    var price: NSString = "1200"
    var title: NSString?
    var desck: NSString?
    var hasPass: Bool?

}

class EFGoodsPayment: EFPaymentObject {

    var pay: NSString = "1"
    var type: NSString = "3"
    var goods: NSString = ""
    var money: NSString?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        money = super.price
    }

}


let payment = EFGoodsPayment()
println(payment.money!)       // prints "1200"
```